# Why is the *ptr in printf?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

In the below code, should the `(*ptr)[1]` not be `(ptr)[1]` instead? As `ptr` is also a pointer as `a` is in `a[][]`.

```
int a[][3] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
int (*ptr)[3] = a;
printf("%d", (*ptr)[1]);
```

Comment: `int a[][3]` is not standard C.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: @chux -- looks okay to me; just as in `int x[] = { 1, 2, 3 };`, where the compiler infers the unspecified dimension from the initializer. `int a[][3]` is more-or-less the same thing. A long-winded version would look like this: `typedef int x[3]; x a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };`. I'm not saying this is a good thing to do, just that it's legal.

Comment: @pete fair enough - I do get warning "warning: missing braces around initializer [-Wmissing-braces]".  Same for [your suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52967427/why-is-the-ptr-in-printf?noredirect=1#comment92844415_52967427).  Expect something like `int a[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}};`

Comment: @chux -- yup; the rules say that you don't need the curly braces, but leaving them out makes it much harder to understand what the initializer means. A fully-braced initializer for this example would be `{ { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 } }`, since each element of `a` is an array of 3 ints. This makes it clearer that there are 2 of those elements.

Answer (score 5):

No.

- `a` is an array of arrays.
- `ptr` is a pointer to [the first element of] that array of arrays.
- `*ptr` is the first element of that array (which is itself an array!).

  - This can also be written `ptr[0]` (because `*(a+n)` is `a[n]`).
- `(*ptr)[1]` is the first element in that result.

  - This can also be written `ptr[0][1]`.
  - It would be more clearly written as `a[0][1]`.

Your proposed counter-example of `ptr[1]` is the *next* element in the result, still an array.

That declaration is dodgy too; the initializer is technically valid but doesn't do what you think, as it only *appears* to list a single dimension.

Overall it's not great code.

Comment: "`ptr` is a pointer to that array of arrays." No. `ptr` is a pointer to an array

Comment: @newacct Right, and that's exactly what I said.

Comment: You said "`ptr` is a pointer to that array of arrays", which sounds like `ptr` is a pointer to an array of arrays, which is not the right type. `ptr` is a pointer to an array of `int`s.

Comment: @newacct `ptr` is a pointer to one or more arrays of `int`s, just like how `int*` is a pointer to one or more `int`s. Admittedly this is only one way to spin it due to how weird pointers are. You're talking about the literal interpretation of the type, whereas I'm talking about semantics. I'd say neither is wrong.

Comment: `ptr` only points to one array of `int`. If you know that that array is an element of an array of arrays, then you can use pointer arithmetic to get a pointer to the next element (or previous element, if it's not the first). But that doesn't change the fact that `ptr` only still points to one array of `int`. The thing it points to may or may not be an element of an array, and it doesn't know that. Using sloppy language confuses learners; `int *` is not a "pointer to array of `int`s", because that is, say `int (*)[42]`.

Comment: @newacct I added in a parenthetical so both interpretations are covered, but I maintain that either interpretation is valid depending on what level of abstraction you're employing in conversation.